# d3.js Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

When I try to layout my force-directed graph, the following is the error I receive. I read about this issue in Mike Bostock's github page and found that it might be due to NaN values of coordinates or all the points drawn at the same point. I checked into the console and I found that all of my points are getting drawn at the same X and Y values.

On an example data, the code worked perfectly well but no more now. My data goes like 45-50 levels away from the center node. I have successfully made a tree layout with this data. Wanted to try the force directed layout but it did not work.

Any help regarding how to draw the nodes on separate coordinates would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force().charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    //.attr("pointer-events","all")
    .append('svg:g')
    //.call(d3.behavior.zoom().translate([100,50]).scale(.5).on("zoom",redraw))
    .append('svg:g')
    .attr("transform","translate(100,50)scale(.5,.5)");

svg.append('svg:rect')
   .attr('width', width)
   .attr('height', height)
   .attr('fill','white')
   .attr('opacity',0);

function redraw() {
  var trans = d3.event.translate;
  var scale = d3.event.scale;
  svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + trans + ")"
      + " scale(" + scale + ")");
};

d3.json("test_data.json", function(error, graph) {

  var nodeMap = {};
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
  graph.links = graph.links.map(
  function(x) 
  {
    return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value
        };
  });
    console.log(graph.nodes);
    console.log(graph.links);
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { 
        //console.log(d.value);
        return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)

      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on("mousedown",
        function(d) {
          d.fixed = true;
          d3.select(this).classed("sticky", true);
        }
          )
      .on("mouseover",fade(0.1))
      .on("mouseout",fade(1));


    var linkedByIndex = {};
    graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
    });

    function isConnected(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
    }

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { 
        return "Name : "+d.name+"\n"+"Parent: "+d.parent +"\n"+"Relationship: "+ d.relationship +"\n"+ "Creation Date: "+ d.cod +"\n"; });

    function fade(opacity)
  {
            return function(d) {
            node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
            });

            link.style("stroke-opacity", opacity).style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
            });
        };
  }

 force.on("tick", function() {

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    /*node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });*/
  });
});

</script>
```

The JSON looks like:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "source": "Me",
            "target": "Adam",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "source": "Me",
            "target": "You",
            "value": 10
        }
    ], "nodes": [
             {
            "ancestor": "Adam",
            "cod": 19061964,
            "distance": 0,
            "name": "Adam",
            "parent": null,
            "relationship": null,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "ancestor": "Adam",
            "cod": 13032003,
            "distance": 1,
            "name": "Me",
            "parent": "You",
            "relationship": "Father",
            "value": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:** I get the error in the following statement:

```
force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();
```

highlighting:

```
"start();"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your data your links are to names as opposed to indices. Check out the example data from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045.

Links have the form: `{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}`, which points to the index of the node.

Comment: IF you notice after the line:

d3.json("test_data.json", function(error, graph)

There is a mapping between the links and the nodes so that links do not need to have that format. I looked into that part earlier.

Comment: Added the line of the error and error is the title of the post