# PSA: d3 doesn't allow too many edges attached to the same node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a project which involves building very large networks from data, and I'm using d3 force layouts for visualization.  Recently I started getting the error:

"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

from certain data sets but not others.  After ripping a few handfuls of hair out, I tried imposing constraints on the number of edges adjacent to a single node, and sure enough the error went away (and the visualization worked as expected) when the constraint was set low enough (the break point was around 2000 edges).  I didn't see this documented anywhere, so I thought it would be useful to ask about the problem here.  Specifically:

- Is the number of allowed edges platform dependent?
- Is this at all affected by the force layout parameters?
- Are there any hacks or workarounds?
- Are there other graph layout platforms for d3 which avoid this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please? It sounds like you may have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Alternative graph layout engine: https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'll need to do some refactoring before I can provide a complete example, but the problem is definitely not my code.  With most data sets it runs fine, and even for those data sets which trigger the error I am able to eliminate the error simply by limiting the number of edges per node.  For instance, one particular data set works if I limit to 2060 edges per node but not 2061 (and there is nothing unusual about the 2061st edge).

Comment: Also, the meaning of the call stack error is that there is infinite (or at least excessive) recursion, not an infinite loop.  I don't know how d3 works under the hood, but this would all makes sense if the selectAll function selects edges recursively.

Comment: @MauricioPoppe Thanks for the link - that looks like a very nice engine.  At first glance, however, I'm not sure it will help with my issue; the documentation says "it may be less scalable to very large graphs.
However, it works well on an average machine on graphs with fewer than 100 nodes."

Comment: Yep that's right Paul, I don't think the call stack error is due to the select code, this might occur because of the [relaxation process](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L58-L129) which applies forces to each node based on d3's force layout initial configuration, I think you should check first if the error is because of multiple calls to this method

Comment: @MauricioPoppe That would also make sense!  I'll see if I can track down the offending function...

Comment: @PaulSiegel I don't mean an infinite loop in your code, but caused by your data. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2408 and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/892

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Oh, I see - thanks for the references, that is the first discussion of this issue that I've seen.  I'll read further!

Comment: @PaulSiegel This has come up a number of times, e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279922/d3-js-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error (which may also be the cause of your problem). You shouldn't have any trouble finding more references.